# Uploading file to EC2 Web Server from Web Application

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, upload, sails.js, multipartform-data

I am creating a simple application using Sails.js. What it basically does is it creates a new Item then saves it to the database and uploads the image to S3.

Here's what happens:
When I run my application on my local, it behaves okay. The req.body has contents, and the req.file('item-image') is not empty.
I am running it on EC2 now, and the problem is, the req.body is just an empty object, but the req.file('item-image') is not empty. I've tried different debugging scenarios, see them below:

1. If I remove the enctype="multipart/form-data" (I know this is needed for file upload, just trying), I get the req.body object that I expect, but as expected, the req.file('item-image') is empty.
2. I put back the enctype="multipart/form-data" then tried sending the request without the file, I get my expected req.body object.
3. I included an image on my request, the req.body object is empty, but the req.file('item-image') isn't.

The weirdest part is, when I send my request through postman, all behaves as expected. I'm really lost now, see my code below:

**create_event.ejs**

```html
<form action=<%= event.createUrl %> method="POST" id="form-item" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="blue bigger">Please fill the following form fields</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body overflow-visible">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
          <div class="space"></div>

          <input type="file" name="item-image"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-field-username">Name</label>

            <div>
              <input class="input-large" type="text" id="form-field-username" placeholder="Item Name" name="item-name" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="space-4"></div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-field-username">Description</label>

            <div>
              <input class="input-large" type="text" id="form-field-username" placeholder="Item Description" name="item-description"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">
        <i class="icon-remove"></i>
        Cancel
      </button>

      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="save-item">
        <i class="icon-ok"></i>
        Save
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

**create_event.js**

```
$('#save-item').on('click', function(e){
        var response = confirm('Are you sure you want to continue saving this item?');
        if(response == true) {
            $('#form-item').submit();
        }
    });
```

**AdminController.js**

```
createItem: function(req, res){
    console.log('Saving..');
    console.log(req.body);
    var eventId = req.path.split('/')[4];
    req.file('item-image').upload(function callback(error, uploadedFile){
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
            return res.serverError();
        }
        console.log(uploadedFile);

        s3Helper.upload(uploadedFile[0], function(error, data){
            if(error) {
                return res.serverError();
            }

            var item = {
                ITEM_ID: uuid.v1(),
                EVENT_ID: req.path.split('/')[4],
                NAME: req.body['item-name'],
                DESCRIPTION: req.body['item-description'],
                IMAGE_URL: data.Location
            }

            EventItem.create(item, function(error, data){
                if(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    return res.serverError();
                }
                console.log('Successfully saved data: ');
                console.log(data);
                return res.redirect('/admin/events/' + eventId);
            });
        });
    });
},
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you attached IAM role with S3 permission on launching EC2 instance?

Comment: Yes, there is enough permission for it to upload and access S3 files

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2508

Apparently, sails.js uses skipper and is sensitive on the order of the input. I just put the file part on the end and it now works.

I'm just confused as to why it works on my local, and not on my ec2 server.